# Select all rows from one table and one specific value for each row from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, conditional-statements

Good afternoon lads, I am trying to make a page where I can check which bosses I did today. I have two tables (table with bosses and table with boss times). Now I need to show all bosses but for each of them I only want to show the closest time when the boss is going to spawn.

The select so far looks like that:

```
$timePlus = strtotime($currentTime) + 60*60*2.2;
$timePlusForm = date("H:i:s", $timePlus);
$userNametoLower = strtolower($userName);
$userTableName = "".$userNametoLower."_bosses";
$currentTime = date("H:i:s", time());
"SELECT `bossTime`.`ID`, `bossTime`.`bossID`, `bossTime`.`time`, `$userTableName`.`ID`, `$userTableName`.`name`, 
                  `$userTableName`.`zone`, `$userTableName`.`map`, `$userTableName`.`waypointCode`, `$userTableName`.`bossDone`
                  FROM `bossTime` LEFT JOIN `$userTableName` ON `$userTableName`.`ID` = `bossTime`.`bossID`
                  WHERE `bossTime`.`time` BETWEEN '$currentTime' AND '$timePlusForm'
                  GROUP BY `bossTime`.`bossID`
                  ORDER BY `bossTime`.`time` ASC";
```

The problem is that this select does not pick the next closest value from time table. I also tried BETWEEN and it also didn't work (some bosses got correct closest time but other got the second closest). Any idea how to solve this is welcomed.

Comment: I think you want the min(`bossTime`.`time`) for each boss

Comment: Yeah, the first line is not the problem. If I use the BETWEEN condition I am able to get all the times right but it only returns 11 records (there are 13 bosses).

Alex - But that would pick the lowest value in table and I need to get the first value which is bigger than currentTime.

Comment: Between is basically > and <. So if 2 of your bosses will respawn after $timePlusForm, you won't get them (11 rows instead of 13). Using only > makes more sense to me.

Comment: Funny, I removed GROUP BY and changed the condition to WHERE `bossTime`.`time` >= '$currentTime' AND `bossTime`.`time` <='$timePlusForm' and for some reason it works ... Alex - I tried that and it picked random values, not the next biggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed GROUP BY and changed the condition to WHERE bossTime.time >= '$currentTime' AND bossTime.time <='$timePlusForm' and for some reason it works